# Operating sytem to install openstack

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, cloud, openstack

I want to create own cloud using OpenStack.

1.) I want to know the best operating system on which I can deploy OpenStack project. Presently I am using ubuntu 12.04.

2.) Which is the shortest way to install OpenStack?

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Shortest way to install OpenStack is to use [DevStack](http://devstack.org/).

Comment: DevStack is an ephemeral installation intended specifically for development.

Comment: it is not the shortest way. It is the shortest way if you are planning to contribute code for openstack

Answer (score 0):

I guess Ubuntu is the best option. I tried it with Fedora but there were some issues. So, I moved back to Ubuntu. Though you might want to try RHEL too. But if you want the easiest route, Ubuntu is the way to go.

Comment: RHEL doesn't have openvswitch and has other major incompatibilities.  RedHat themselves use fedora for OpenStack deployment.

Comment: Oops! Actually one of my friends told me that he installed Openstack using packstack and it was quite an easy process. I had some serious issues with Fedora. Since then, I always prefer Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu was the distribution that nova was originally developed on.  It has become the defacto standard for OpenStack development.  12.04 works fine, and the cloud archive that ubuntu operates contains semi supported backports of the latest stable releases of OpenStack including dependencies that will work on 12.04.

Saucy has more active development of Havana packages and dependencies.

I would recommend checking out :

http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack is well supported on most distros now. I would choose the distro based on other factors at this stage. For completeness, openvswitch and network namespaces are supported on RHEL and Fedora now. For details of installing on RHEL/Centos/Fedora please see:

http://openstack.redhat.com/

There is a 3 step process to install various versions of OpenStack on Red Hat flavors

Answer (score 0):

1) ubuntu 12.04 TLS Server edition
2) For development, install devstack; for product env, install it following the installation guide.